# Ruby 1.9.x replace sets of characters with specific cleaned up characters in a string

Tags: ruby, utf-8, transliteration

I'm looking for a way to do the following PHP code in Ruby in a succinct and efficient manner:

```
$normalizeChars = array('Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
        'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
        'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
        'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
        'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
        'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
        'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f');
$cleanGenre = strtr($this->entryArray['genre'], $normalizeChars);
```

Here the `strtr()` function will replace the character on the left with the one on the right in the array. Pretty handy for a cleanup job. But I can't seem to find anywhint similar in Ruby, that is, a way to specify which characters to replace all in one array rather than with lengthy conditionals for each character.

Note that `tr` won't work cause you can't replace one letter with two (D => Dj). Plus it gives me an `InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xC5" on US-ASCII` for this line:

```
    entry["genre"].tr('ŠšŽž', 'SsZz')
```

Thanks.

Comment: would this work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7836947/166029 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make it easy for you to implement

```
#encoding: UTF-8
t = 'ŠšÐŽžÀÁÂÃÄAÆAÇÈÉÊËÌÎÑNÒOÓOÔOÕOÖOØOUÚUUÜUÝYÞBßSàaáaâäaaæaçcèéêëìîðñòóôõöùûýýþÿƒ'
fallback = { 
  'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
  'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
  'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
  'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
  'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
  'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
  'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f'
  }

p t.encode('us-ascii', :fallback => fallback)
```

Comment: Thanks peter. I'm still having that error in the app where it doesn't accept any of these characters so I can't really test it. But I shall as soon as I can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: could be an encoding from one of your gems, can you run the codesnippet i provided by itself ? Also make sure to save the script itzself also in UTF-8

Comment: peter, a million thanks, this did the trick and you were nice enough to take the time to write out all the needed characters. You went way above an beyond and I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.9.3 you can use the `:fallback` option with `encode`:

```
"ŠšŽžÐ".encode('us-ascii', :fallback => { [your character table here] })
=> "SsZzDj"
```

It's also possible to do it with `gsub` as it accepts a conversion table as a hash argument in 1.9.x:

```
"ŠšŽžÐ".gsub(/[ŠšŽžÐ]/, [your character table here])
=> "SsZzDj"
```

Or better yet (by @steenslag):

```
character_table = [your table here]
regexp_keys     = Regexp.union(character_table.keys) 
"ŠšŽžÐ".gsub(regexp_keys, character_table)
=> "SsZzDj"
```

This sort of character conversion is called [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration), which is good to know if you wish to google for more solutions (there are many Ruby libraries that support transliteration, but none of the ones I tested supported your character set completely).

Comment: Thanks a lot Casper, I shall give it a try. A problem I have is that I can't test anything in the console with special characters, pasting your `gsub` example gives me this horrible thing: `"\U+FFC5\U+FFA0\U+FFC5\U+FFA1\U+FFC5\U+FFBD\U+FFC5\U+FFBE\U+FFC3".gsub(/[\U+FFC5\U+FFA0\U+FFC5\U+FFA1\U+FFC5\U+FFBD\U+FFC5\U+FFBE\U+FFC3]/, ['SsZzDj'])`. Adding it to the code, gives me the `InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xC5" on US-ASCI` error. I really don't know why.

Comment: @kakubei There are several reasons why that could be happening. Your terminal might not support UTF8, or your `LANG` shell environment might not be set up properly. You might want to post a question on superuser or a new stackoverflow question. However this might also fix it: run irb like so: `irb -E UTF-8`.

Comment: Note you can generate the Regular expression for the `gsub` example : `re = Regexp.union(character_table.keys); "ŠšŽžÐ".gsub(re, character_table)`.

Comment: @steenslag - Nice. Added to answer also. Thank you.

Comment: Still working on getting the console to accept special characters. Not even with `irb -E UTF-8`. Will post another question for it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works as I suppose you'd like it to have: translating characters in the array and leaving those not in there as they are:

```
# encoding: utf-8
lookup = {'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A',
        'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I',
        'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U',
        'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a',
        'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i',
        'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u',
        'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f'}

clean_genre = entry["genre"].chars.to_a.map { |x|
  if lookup.has_key?(x)
    lookup[x]
  else
    x
  end
}.join
```

for example this:

```
'aŠšŽž'.chars.to_a.map { |x|
  if lookup.has_key?(x)
    lookup[x]
  else
    x
  end
}.join
```

gives you 'aSsZz'.

Or move the block logic into the lookup table itself (thanks to steenslag for simplifying the default proc solution!):

```
lookup.default_proc = proc { |hash, key| key }
```

then the call would look as follows:

```
puts 'aŠšŽž'.chars.to_a.map { |x| lookup[x] }.join
```

Or even better (thanks again to steenslag for pointing out):

```
puts 'aŠšŽž'.gsub(/./) { |x| lookup[x] }
```

Comment: The default_proc of a Hash runs by definition when the key is not found; no need to check for that. `lookup.default_proc = proc{|_, key| key}` suffices.

Comment: In addition, with such a lookup table (with default_proc) you could do: `puts 'aŠšŽž'.gsub(/./){ |x| lookup[x] }`.